# Print lines between (and including) two patterns

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep

I want to start grepping from the lines that has `CK` at the end of line and stop grepping when the line has `D` at the end. I tried `grep "$CK" "$D" file..txt`, but it didn't work.

Input:

```
kkkkkkkkkkk   
jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj  
gggggggggggg/CK  
JHGHHHHHHHH   
HJKHKKLKLLL   
JNBHBHJKJJLKKL  
JLKKKLLKJLKJ/D  
GGGGGGGGGGGGGG  
GGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

The desired output:

```
gggggggggggg/CK  
JHGHHHHHHHH   
HJKHKKLKLLL   
JNBHBHJKJJLKKL  
JLKKKLLKJLKJ/D
```

Answer (score 33):

You are better off using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) or [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
awk '/CK$/,/D$/' file.txt
```

OR

```
sed -n '/CK$/,/D$/p' file.txt
```

If you insist on [grep](/questions/tagged/grep), here's a GNU grep way

```
grep -oPz '(?s)(?<=\n)\N+CK\n.*?D(?=\n)' file.txt
```

Here

`-P` activates perl-regexp

`-z` sets line separator to NUL. This forces grep to see the entire file as one single line

`-o` prints only matching

`(?s)` activates PCRE_DOTALL, so `.` finds any character or newline

`\N` matches anything except newline

`.*?` finds . in nongreedy mode

`(?<=..)` is a look-behind assertion

`(?=..)` is a look-ahead assertion

Comment: why not added slash ? like this `awk '/\/CK/,/\/D/' input`

Comment: @RahulPatil, that's because the OP stated 'start grepping from the lines that has "CK" at the end of line and stop grepping when the line has "D"'

Comment: it seems me, you have strong understanding of regex.. I didn't understand that level, so could you please explain that last of PCRE grep

Comment: @RahulPatil, added some explanation :-)

Comment: @RohitPatil, I want to delete the matching selection from the file. can i do that?

Comment: @RanaKhan, what does the first line come back stating when you run `sed --version` on your system?

Comment: so basically the block that i want to remove has the first line that end with "CK \" and last line that end with "RD \". I am trying the following :
sed -n '/CK \\$/,/D \\$/' script.tcl | more
and it does not work , it says " sed: -e expression #1, char 16: missing command"

Comment: @RanaKhan, you need `sed -n '/CK \\$/,/D \\$/p' script.tcl`

Comment: this does not delete this block. it only shows it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11419/discussion-between-1-cr-and-rana-khan)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using BSD `grep` (doesn't support perl regex param `-P`), here is the workaround:

```
grep -o "aaa.*cdn" <(paste -sd_ file) | tr '_' '\n'
```

This works by concatenating all lines (replacing new lines with `_` character), checking the one-line pattern and expanding the lines back to its original state.

If you're using GNU `grep`, you can achieve multiline match in `grep`, but you need to use perl-regexp for `grep` (`-P`) like mentioned in another [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99432/21471). You can still install GNU `grep` on macOS via `brew install grep` and use `ggrep` instead.

---

Alternatively you can use [`pcregrep`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/152708/55075) which supports multi-line patterns (`-M`).

---

You can also use `ex` command, e.g.:

```
ex +"/aaa/;/cdn/p" -scq! file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`awk '/CK$/{f=1}/D$/{f=0;print;exit}f' filename

gggggggggggg/CK
JHGHHHHHHHH
HJKHKKLKLLL
JNBHBHJKJJLKKL
JLKKKLLKJLKJ/D
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Perl(5):**

```
perl -nE 'print $_ if /CK$/.../D$/;'
```

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6):**

```
raku -ne 'put $_ if /CK$/fff/D$/;'
```

Both lines of code above use a sed-like "flip-flop" operator. In Perl5 the sed-like "flip-flop" is spelled `...`. In Raku the sed-like "flip-flop" is spelled `fff`.

Sample Input:

```
kkkkkkkkkkk   
jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj  
gggggggggggg/CK  
JHGHHHHHHHH   
HJKHKKLKLLL   
JNBHBHJKJJLKKL  
JLKKKLLKJLKJ/D  
GGGGGGGGGGGGGG  
GGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

Sample Output (either Perl5 or Raku):

```
gggggggggggg/CK
JHGHHHHHHHH
HJKHKKLKLLL
JNBHBHJKJJLKKL
JLKKKLLKJLKJ/D
```

Note, because Raku uses the `.` dot to chain operations, the Raku code starting `put $_` … can be written `$_.put` … . Also, if a method chain starts with a `.` dot, Raku defaults to calling the chain on the `$_` topic variable. Thus the Raku code presented above can be shortened to `$_.put` … and even further shortened to `.put` … .

https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop
https://raku.org